# Principal component analysis in FLink

Tags: apache-flink

Is there any way to use `PCA` in Apache Flink?

When I googled it for my research, I think that no implemented code can be found.

If so, should I develop it by myself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this would be for Flink batch mode (processing a bounded DataSet), right?

There is this (stalled?) work in progress for [FLINK-1733](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-1733). Though based on the [code review comments](https://github.com/nguyent/flink/commit/8f198edcf26c6a98f8c7cdb7c30ef96632ec6f8c) it doesn't seem like it's ready for Prime Time.

No idea if this is useful, but you can [read here](https://mahout.apache.org/users/algorithms/d-spca.html) about how Mahout implements its version of distributed PCA. This gives you the broad-stroke overview of the algorithm, as it's written using Mahout's R-ish syntax that gets translated into a Spark job.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you wanna do? Train a model? Apply an existing one? There are actually no restrictions. Flink is, in simple words, a streaming framework. What operation you apply to your data is up to you and not depending on the framework (Flink).

Comment: I mean, I have existing pca framework, but it only works on the single machine not a distributed machines. Given this consideration, I assume that it seems to not work well when I use the existing pca framework because the flink is distributed machines.

Comment: What exactly is your use case? Train a model? Or use an existing one?

Comment: my scenario is the training a model.

Comment: Right. But I have no references for flink

Comment: There is nothing in place which I am aware of. Spark has an implementation which works distributed. Maybe you can adopt some ideas. Why do you wanna use flink for it? Training a model is something what you might wanna do with a well defined train and test set. Sounds more like a batch approach - therefor it might be worth having a closer look at spark.